# Immuable Object creation

Tags: java, class, immutability

Is this a immuable class ?
is it necessary for a immutable class to be final  ?

I have a box class that is to be immuable , changes to a box should create a new box .

```
public class MyImmutableBox {
    Integer length;
    Integer breadth;

    /*Constructor*/

    public MyImmutableBox(Integer length,Integer breadth){
        this.length=length;
        this.breadth=breadth;
    }

    /*Getters*/ 

    public Integer getBreadth() {
        return breadth;
    }
    public Integer getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /*Member functions*/

    /*Changing entire box size*/
    public MyImmutableBox changeMyBoxSize(Integer lengthToBeAltered,Integer breadthToBeAltered){
        return new MyImmutableBox(length+lengthToBeAltered,breadth+breadthToBeAltered);
    }

    /*Changing either length otr breadth*/  

    public MyImmutableBox changeMyBoxLenth(Integer lengthToBeAltered){
        return new MyImmutableBox(length+lengthToBeAltered,breadth);
    }

    public MyImmutableBox changeMyBoxBreadth(Integer breadthToBeAltered){
        return new MyImmutableBox(length,breadth+breadthToBeAltered);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's definitely not immutable. Your `length` and `breadth` fields aren't private or readonly, so this code will work:

```
MyImmutableBox box = new ImmutableBox(5, 3);
box.length = 10;
box.breadth = 20;
```

(It's not clear why you're using `Integer` rather than `int`, by the way.)

If you *either* make the fields private and avoid modifying them within your class, *or* make them final, *or* (preferrably) both, then the type as you've shown it will be immutable. It won't prevent mutable subclasses though - you should make the class final at the same time to do that.

Comment: +1. How does the mutability of the subclass affect the immutability of superclass ?

Comment: @Santosh: Typically immutability is useful for clients to know that they don't need to make defensive copies, that they can use an object freely across threads, etc. That's a property of an *object* - so if I don't know whether an object I'm using is *actually* an instance of just the immutable class or an instance of the mutable subclass, it doesn't help me much.